# jQuery change input.value on keyup() only works in FF 3.6

Tags: jquery, input, keyup

Ok, so I'm finally getting into jQuery but having what I hope are basic issues getting my functions to run. I have 3 input fields on a page, two of them are disabled. My goal is that when the user enters text into the first input field, the values of the other 2 fields would be changed on keyup() to the value entered by the user in the first input field.

I tested my function on jsfiddle.net before I was able to put it on my page and it worked fine in all browser, but once i move that function to my web page and run it the function won't work. It seems to work in Firefox 3.6 but not any versions after that. It also doesn't work in chrome or IE for some reason either.

[jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qrLV3/)

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $title2 = $("#title2"),
        $title3 = $("#title3");
    $("#cheader").keyup(function () {
        $title2.val(this.value);
        $title3.val(this.value);
    });
    $("#cheader").blur(function () {
        $title2.val(this.value);
        $title3.val(this.value);
    });​
});
```

CSS

```
.nobox {
border: none;
text-align: center;
color: #000;
background-color: #fff;
text-decoration: underline; 
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 14px;
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" onClick="if(this.value=='Click Here To Enter Text'){this.value=''}else{this.value=this.value}" onBlur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Click Here To Enter Text'}" style="width:250px;" class="nobox" value="Click Here To Enter Text" maxlength="35" id="cheader"/>

<input type="text" style="width:250px;" class="cheader nobox" value="Click Here To Enter Text" id="title2" disabled disabled="disabled"/>​

<input type="text" style="width:250px;" class="cheader nobox" value="Click Here To Enter Text" id="title3" disabled disabled="disabled"/>​
```

Comment: I don't see any reason it shouldn't work. Can you reproduce the problem in a fiddle? It's probably something to do with your other code.

Comment: Do you see any javascript errors in other browsers?

Comment: The fiddle you posted is working as you describe in Firefox, IE and Chrome.. So it must be something else messing with your code..

Comment: Error: illegal character
Line: 24, Column: 3
Source Code:
});​

Which is the closing bracket of that function.

Comment: Thats the only error I get when i run the error console in FF. :| I'm not sure what else could be written wrong on my page, everything else works as it should in all browsers except this jquery. It's weird because FF 3.6 works perfectly, but newer versions of FF don't. I guess I'm gunna have to do a lot of review on my other included scripts. Could a line of code from an external script on my page effect this function even though it's written in the head tag of my page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed `$(document).ready(function () {` to `$(function() {` and now everything works fine on all browsers. Not really sure why but it works now :D

```
$(function() {
var $title2 = $("#title2"),
    $title3 = $("#title3");

$("#cheader").keyup(function() {
    $title2.val(this.value);
    $title3.val(this.value);
});
$("#cheader").blur(function() {
    $title2.val(this.value);
    $title3.val(this.value);
});
```

Comment: It can't be the reason why it didn't work. It seems we'll never know why was that.